# search for a DN using substring matching

Tags: search, ldap, openldap

I have an OpenLDAP installation and I need to find an entry, from my custom schema extension, based on a DN value.

To be more specific I have an attribute (certSubjectDN) added to one of my custom classes that contains a DN which is used for certificate based authentication on a web server using smart cards (PKI auth). From what I understand a filtered search with substring matching against Active Directory, e.g. (certSubjectDN=CN=lastname.firstname*), will match against any entry where the value of certSubjectDN begins with 'CN=lastname.firstname'. This does not work with OpenLDAP.

I have attempted to add a matching rule to the attribute, SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch, but OpenLDAP refuses to accept that change, presumably because it is strictly following the LDAP specifications.

Can someone think of a way that I can perform such a substring match against an attribute of the DN type within OpenLDAP? Or should I just change that attribute to be a Directory String?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an OpenLDAP expert, but I think you are on the right path. The DN syntax does not allow substring matching. The string syntax does.

If this fails, I would try to define a custom attribute with string syntax and the appropriate substring matching rule.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah. I currently have it pulling all records containing that attribute, plus another that is needed, then looping through them to find to correct value but I will probably change that attribute type on Monday. Thankfully things are just in the testing phase right now so there's no large dataset to wade through.